# Migrate channels to hangouts chat rooms

Tags: slack, slack-api, google-hangouts

my organization was using Slack, and decided to move to Google Hangouts Chat. I used channels to coordinate with different teams. How do i migrate these users to Hangouts Chat rooms?

(Issue) Chat rooms allow duplicates, and are created private. So new users cannot see them & join. They end up creating copies of a similar common room each time.

Either of the following kinds of options are fine with me.

1. Export users list email-addresses from my Slack channel. Import these users into  Chat as @email-id . I can't seem to get the email-list from Slack
2. Send Chat room shareable invite link to channel users. Google Chat rooms don't give shareable invite link.

Comment: This question is very broad. You basically asking for a complete design for your issue, which is not what SO is about. I vote to close. Please consider reducing your question to one specific coding issue.

Comment: You can get the emails of all you users with [users.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list). Emails need special permissions, so check out the details on that page.

Comment: [tag:hangouts-api] refers to a Google+ Hangouts API. It is now deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Erik said, the operation you are looking for is `users.list`. Though you need to ensure you have `users:read` and `users:read.email` set in your environment. This will also give you a bunch of empty entries though, as it will include all bots and apps on your workspace, which do not have emails.

I wrote a quick app using [Transposit](https://transposit.com) (disclaimer: I work for them) that you can fork [here](https://console.transposit.com/t/griffin/slack2hangouts?readme=true) that will return an array of all valid emails in a Slack organization for you. Authenticate with Slack, and it should work by just running `get_emails.js`.

Unfortunately, we do not yet have a Hangouts connector, so we can't automate the whole process through this app, but I hope you find it helpful! Let me know if you have any questions in a DM, or message us at support@transposit.com.

Best,
Griffin, Developer Advocate at Transposit